# How to toggle using redux in react for a nested link component within a mobile menu

Tags: reactjs, redux

I've created a responsive menu which shares a nav component which has a link component nested inside. So Toolbar > Nav > Link. I also have a Sidebar (Mobile Menu), that shares the Nav and Link Component: Sidebar > Nav > Link.

So I have had some success with toggling the Close and Menu icon and showing and hiding the Mobile Sidebar not using Redux. But I realise with the nesting, passing props beyond parent and child wasn't working for me so I decided to try Redux but the set up is a little complicated, I have tried using console.log to see what is happening but the actions don't seem to subscribe or something is not hooking up to update the state.

Can someone help me see what is going on?

The editor to the project is here, though there is a ES5/ES6 transpile issue on it, I tried installing Babel there but not sure how to resolve on Stackblitz. The code and file structure there:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xey1dv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you wiil have to change your mapStateToProps to listen to particular prop values like the 'isOpened' in reducer.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    isOpened: state.isOpened
  };
};
```

And then in toggleNav you should check the status of this object using 'this.props',

```
if (!this.props.isOpened) {
      openNavigation();
      console.log('active');
    }
    else {
      closeNavigation();
      console.log('not-active');
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Rohith, I have updated my example in Stackblitz, the store I have created in the index.js, the connect() and mapStateToProps() I have added too, for and placed it in components/navigation/toolbar/toolbar. I have a feeling I'm doing something wrong on the click function: toggleNav(), that is meant to update/toggle the state...

Comment: Edited the answer accordingly, pls check

Comment: Yes thank you! I want to use it for the links within my nav which is in a different component Sidebar > Nav > Link, it is correct to set up the same thing in that component?

Comment: Ocourse and you can use same props there also or add more variables in reducer and use props connected to that particular variables in any or ur components.